# React Native progress bar percentage not staying the same after closing the app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Every time I press a button the progress bar will go up %20 but the problem is for instance if its at %80 and I reload the app it will show it as %60 instead, I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this issue to have the progress bars percentage stay the same after reloading or closing the app.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var ProgressBar = require('react-native-progress-bar');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  AsyncStorage,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
  button: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#0059FF',
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#0059FF'
  },
  buttonClear: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#3B3A3A',
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#3B3A3A'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    lineHeight: 33,
    color: '#FFF',
  }
});

var PROGRESS = 0;

class BasicStorageExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: PROGRESS
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('progressbar')
      .then((value) => {
        JSON.parse(value);
        this.setState({
          progress: value 
        });
        console.log('Progress on load: ' + value);
      })
      .done();
  }

  onButtonPress() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('progressbar', JSON.stringify(PROGRESS))
      .then(() => {
        JSON.parse(PROGRESS);
        this.setState({
          progress: PROGRESS += 0.2
        });
        console.log('Progress on Button Press: ' + PROGRESS);
      })
      .done();
  }

  onButtonClearPress() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('progressbar', JSON.stringify(PROGRESS))
      .then(() => {
        JSON.parse(PROGRESS);
        PROGRESS = 0;
        this.setState({
          progress: 0
        });
      })
      .done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ProgressBar
          fillStyle={{}}
          backgroundStyle={{backgroundColor: '#cccccc', borderRadius: 2}}
          style={{marginTop: 10, width: 300}}
          progress={this.state.progress} />
        <TouchableHighlight
          ref="button"
          style={styles.button}
          underlayColor='#002C7F'
          onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Done</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.buttonClear}
          underlayColor='#002C7F'
          onPress={this.onButtonClearPress.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Clear</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BasicStorageExample', () => BasicStorageExample);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the old value of PROGRESS (before you increment by `0.2`) and setting this value to the item `progressbar`.

So, every time you reload, React runs the `componentDidMount` function, and since you set `progressbar` to the old value of PROGRESS, it will always show it one increment behind what you see in the view.

Try changing your `onButtonPress()` to this:

```
onButtonPress() {
    PROGRESS += 0.2;
    AsyncStorage.setItem('progressbar', JSON.stringify(PROGRESS))
    ... // continues normally
```